# application defined or object defined error [when passing a Range object to the Range method]

Tags: vba, excel

I am copying a range from one worksheet to the next using the following code:

```
Private Sub btn_Milestones_Click()
Dim projectref As String
Dim savelocation As String
Dim projectSearchRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim NewWorkbook As Workbook
Dim copy_range As Range

'set search value (porject key - unique)
projectref = cmb_Project.Value

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Workbooks("Project tracker spreadsheet VBA").Activate
'find the project reference in the tracking spreadsheet
With Sheets("Project Tracking")
    Set projectSearchRange = .Range("A:A").Find(projectref, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not projectSearchRange Is Nothing Then '<-- verify that find was successful
        LastRow = projectSearchRange.Row
        'file directory to save the new workbook in
        savelocation = .Cells(LastRow, 5).Value
    Else '<-- find was unsuccessful
        MsgBox "Unable to find " & projectref
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With
Set copy_range = Range(Cells(LastRow, 11), Cells(LastRow, 34))

Worksheets("Milestone_Template").Range(copy_range).Copy 'application defined or object defined error occurs here
Worksheets("Project Tracking").Range("A7:X7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

As the code illustrates, I am looking for a unique reference number in the "Project Tracking" Sheet, then using the row number to define a range to copy. copying that range and pasting the values of that range into a new sheet. However, I am getting the application error on the line indicated in the code. I've triple checked to make sure the worksheet names are correct.

I have a feeling it is to do with the way I've declared the range and how it is attempting to copy the values, but I can not see where it could be throwing this error from.

Can anybody see where I would be getting this error from, and what I need to do to resolve it?

Thanks.

Comment: `Set copy_range = Range(...` should be like `Set copy_range = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Project Tracking").Range(...`. To be honest, your code could do with explicit range references *everywhere*.

Comment: There are 937 existing questions here with the same exact error message. How many of them have you read to see if your answer is there?

Comment: @KenWhite - I have been working on this for the last couple of hours - and after the first 100 - 120 didn't yield a suitable solution for my particular scenario, I assumed that I was doing something else stupid. Not in any way saying that this particular solution wasn't within the 900+ other questions, but when there is a deadline to meet you can only justify fruitless searching for so long.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie - made your suggested change, still throwing the same error in the same place.

Comment: Sorry, but the fact you're in a hurry or have a deadline doesn't change the fact that there is an existing post (or many) that point you in the right direction for a solution. We don't need 10,000 questions about the same exact problem here. (You'll find it's related to the `Set copy_range` line, which I know because I've encountered that answer in several dozen of those existing questions here as they went by - how else do you think I know how many existing posts there are if I hadn't needed to point this out before?)

Comment: Reread @RobinMackenzie's comment. I believe applying that will fix your issue.

Comment: Actually on a 2nd look I think my first comment was wrong because now it looks like `copy_range` is in `Workbooks("Project tracker spreadsheet VBA").Sheets("Project Tracking")`

Comment: @scb998 - make sure every range is set like this: `wb.ws.Range("blah")` where `wb` has been set-up like `Set wb = Workbooks("foo")` and `ws` like `Set ws = ws.Worksheets("bar")` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry you got beat up, I have edited question title so your specific problem is identified.  Here's an attempted answer ...

It is quite difficult to debug without the data but it looks like copy_range is already of type `Range`, you seem to use it on the problem line like it was a `String` range expression like "A1:C3".  So I have rewritten, you can go straight to `copy_range.Copy`.

The commenters are right that full qualification helps clarify issues, so I have done some full qualification but not all.

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub btn_Milestones_Click()
    Dim projectref As String
    Dim savelocation As String
    Dim projectSearchRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim NewWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim copy_range As Range


    'set search value (porject key - unique)
    projectref = cmb_Project.Value

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Workbooks("Project tracker spreadsheet VBA").Activate

    Dim wbSource As Excel.Workbook
    Set wbSource = Workbooks("Project tracker spreadsheet VBA")

    'find the project reference in the tracking spreadsheet
    With Sheets("Project Tracking")
        Set projectSearchRange = .Range("A:A").Find(projectref, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not projectSearchRange Is Nothing Then '<-- verify that find was successful
            LastRow = projectSearchRange.Row
            'file directory to save the new workbook in
            savelocation = .Cells(LastRow, 5).Value
        Else '<-- find was unsuccessful
            MsgBox "Unable to find " & projectref
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    Dim wsMilestoneTempate As Excel.Worksheet
    Set wsMilestoneTempate = wbSource.Worksheets("Milestone_Template")

    Set copy_range = wsMilestoneTempate.Range(wsMilestoneTempate.Cells(LastRow, 11), wsMilestoneTempate.Cells(LastRow, 34))
    copy_range.Copy
    ''''Worksheets("Milestone_Template").Range(copy_range).Copy 'application defined or object defined error occurs here
    Worksheets("Project Tracking").Range("A7:X7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Fantastic! thanks for being helpful and solving the issue - I really do appreciate it.